# Get contact name from GMail API

Tags: php, api, gmail, google-plus

I would like to get the contact name from a GMail address. Is any GMail API to do it? I saw some methods from G+ API but they don't return it.
For example, I would like to use something like this:

> GET
>   https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/findcontact/johndoe@gmail.com/full?updated-min=2007-03-16T00:00:00

And get this:

> {name: John Doe}

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible, at least not with a public API for obvious privacy reasons.